# What is the relationship between the IP address and MAC address?

Tags: ip, mac-address, layer2, ip-address, layer3

I own a MAC address and I want to know from it, the IP address.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPi5Nvxaosw) might help make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) cache is the the link between them. The *Address Resolution Protocol* is responsible for converting an IP-address to a MAC-address.

Comment: The ARP cache will have the layer-3 to layer-2 resolution for some devices on the network (not all), but not for your device. I don't think this answers the question, but it may be part of what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There is no relationship. A MAC Address is a layer-2 address, and an IP address is a layer-3 address. The network layers are independent of each other.

A MAC address can have different layer-3 protocols with different layer-3 addresses. There were even implementations of networks which used only layer-2.

Comment: Can I get my place in the map by MAC address

Comment: What map? A MAC address is assigned by the NIC manufacturer. It is 48 bits long, the first 24 bits are assigned by IEEE to the manufacturer, and the manufacturer assigns the last 24 bits. Randomly connecting machines to a network (a normal situation) will result in random MAC addresses on the network.

Comment: @user20508 No. You can not use a MAC address to determine your geographic location.

Answer (score 0):

MAC address and IP address are completely different, MAC Address is a unique address given to a machine by the manufacturer, though there are different manufacturers making various machines, it's their commitment to make sure every network machine on the planet has a unique MAC id.

IP address is used to identify a machine over the Internet, usually IPV4 addresses which are assigned by the international authority of assigned numbers..
For machines which are using internet through a single IP address(public) and a private IP address (need not be unique on the planet) are connected to a router which uses ARP to supervise the communications of machines under the same router(gate way of the lan).
ARP-adresss resolution protocol uses the MAC id to find the private IP address of the machine,ARP runs at the router...